# A question relevant to EGZ theorem?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose we call $A(n)$ is clause : Let $n\ge 1$ and $a_1,...,a_{2n-1}\in \mathbb{Z}$. There exist distinct $i_1,...,i_n$ such that $a_{i_1}+...+a_{i_n}\equiv 0(\text{ mod }n)$.

I try prove that: If $A(m),A(n)$ are true, we have $A(mn)$ is also true. But I don't succecced.

This is my attemp:

> Because $A(m),A(n)$ are true, so in $2mn-1$ numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_{2mn-1}$. We always find $mn$ numbers satisfied their's sum divides by $n$ or $m$. But, I can't prove that: Exist $mn$ numbers satisfied their's sum devides by $mn$. Can you help me this stuck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A(n)$ is true, then since $2mn - 1 \ge 2n - 1$, among those integers there's $n$ of them which sum to a multiple of $n$, say $k_1n$, with $k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Remove this group of $n$ integers to its own group, so you're left with $(2m - 1)n - 1$ integers. If $m \gt 1$, then $(2m - 1)n - 1 \ge 2n - 1$, so you can find another group of $n$ integers which sum to a multiple of $n$, say $k_2n$, with $k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Once again, remove this group of $n$ integers into a separate group. You can repeat this $2m - 1$ times to get that same number of groups set aside, with the $i$'th (for each $1 \le i \le 2m - 1$) group having a sum of $k_i n$, for some $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Consider the $k_i$, for $1 \le i \le 2m - 1$, as a group of integers. If $A(m)$ is true, there's $m$ of the $k_i$ intgers which sum to a multiple of $m$, say $qm$, with $q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Take the $m$ groups of the associated $n$ integers, say with indices $i_j$ for $1 \le j \le m$, for a total of $mn$ integers, to get their total sum is

$$S = \sum_{j=1}^{2m-1}k_{i_j} n = n\sum_{j=1}^{2m-1}k_{i_j} = n(qm) = q(mn) \tag{1}$$

Thus, if $A(m)$ and $A(n)$ are true, you have $mn$ integers from among $2mn-1$ integers which sum to a multiple of $mn$, i.e., $A(mn)$ is also true.

FYI, this is an example of the [Zero sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_problem). Also, note the proof above is very similar to what is in the second page of the [original paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2860/2b7734c115bbab7141a1942a2c974057ddc0.pdf) of Erdős, Ginzburg and Ziv.